# Java Async NIO servlet not working as expected

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, nio

I'm trying to put working a simple servlet (copied from another source). It's an async servlet that reads a post request using NIO through a ReadListener. This is the code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "AsyncProxyServlet2", urlPatterns = "/*" , asyncSupported = true)
public class AsyncProxyServlet2 extends HttpServlet 
{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 8458401860448619054L;

 @Override
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
 {
  final AsyncContext acontext = request.startAsync();
  final ServletInputStream input = request.getInputStream();
  System.out.println("request.isAsyncStarted() = " + request.isAsyncStarted() + ", request.isAsyncSupported = " + request.isAsyncSupported() + ", main = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());  

  input.setReadListener(new ReadListener()
  {
   byte tmp[] = new byte[4*1024];
   ByteArrayOutputStream buffer     = new ByteArrayOutputStream(this.tmp.length);

   @Override
   public void onDataAvailable() 
   {
    try 
    {
     System.out.println("onDataAvailable = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());    
     int numBytesRead = -1;

     while ( input.isReady() && !input.isFinished() )
     {
      if ( (numBytesRead = input.read(this.tmp)) > 0 ) this.buffer.write(this.tmp, 0, numBytesRead);
     }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
   }

   @Override
   public void onAllDataRead() 
   {
    try 
    {
     System.out.println("onAllDataRead = " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", buffer size = " + this.buffer.size());    

     acontext.getResponse().setContentType("text/xml; charset=utf-8");
     acontext.getResponse().setContentLength(this.buffer.size());
     acontext.getResponse().getOutputStream().write(this.buffer.toByteArray());
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

    acontext.complete();
   }

   @Override
   public void onError(Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }
  });

  System.out.println("final 1");
  try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (Exception e) {}
  System.out.println("final 2");
 }
```

}

When I send a post request to this servlet, the output of this code is:

```
request.isAsyncStarted() = true, request.isAsyncSupported = true, main = http-nio-80-exec-1
final 1
<-- Here a 3 second pause
final 2
onDataAvailable = http-nio-80-exec-1
onAllDataRead = http-nio-80-exec-1, buffer size = 910
```

So it seems that everything is executed on the same thread. The request is not read until the 3-second pause ends, then the last 3 messages are printed.

Why is this not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3 seconds pause...

`try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (Exception e) {}`

Just comment out this line.

Comment: Without the pause the result is the same. My question is: the onDataAvailable and onAlldataRead should not show another different thread that the main thread?